# How to click a href link using selenium in Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, href

I use Selenium in Python to login on a portal. Once on the portal, I want to click a button to view a report. In the HTML code, the button is a href link:

```
<a href="Transactions.aspx">
```

I have tried several selectors from the find_element command. Most logical one was to copy the XPATH from the webpage. This is the code that I have:

```
webdriver_path = r'C:/Users/abcd/webdriver/'
driver = webdriver.Edge(webdriver_path)

driver.get('https://www.sepay.nl/mysepay/Login.aspx')

username_field = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$loginPopup$loginPopup$txtLogin')
password_field = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$loginPopup$loginPopup$txtPassword')

username_field.send_keys('abcd')
password_field.send_keys('abcd')

input_field = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$loginPopup$loginPopup$btnLogin$btnLogin')
input_field.click()

transacties = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_pnlQuickLinksInfo"]/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/a')
transacties.click()
```

The error report is following:

```
NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[23], line 15
     12 input_field = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$loginPopup$loginPopup$btnLogin$btnLogin')
     13 input_field.click()
---> 15 transacties = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_pnlQuickLinksInfo"]/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/a')
     16 transacties.click()

File c:\Users\abcd\webdriver.py:831, in WebDriver.find_element(self, by, value)
    828     by = By.CSS_SELECTOR
    829     value = f'[name="{value}"]'
--> 831 return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]

File c:\Users\abcd\webdriver.py:440, in WebDriver.execute(self, driver_command, params)
    438 response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    439 if response:
--> 440     self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    441     response["value"] = self._unwrap_value(response.get("value", None))
    442     return response

File c:\Users\abcd\errorhandler.py:245, in ErrorHandler.check_response(self, response)
    243         alert_text = value["alert"].get("text")
    244     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)  # type: ignore[call-arg]  # mypy is not smart enough here
--> 245 raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
...
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF73FBBF01C+798252]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF73FBB50D1+757473]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFB2C187614+20]
    RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFB2C2C26A1+33]
```

How do I select the href item?

Comment: Please post the code as text not screenshot.

Comment: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Your XPath does not match any element, therefore `find_element` raises a 
`NoSuchElementException`. Without access to the full html that you target, we can't tell you what the correct XPath would be.

Comment: Hi toyota Supra, posted as proposed.

Comment: Hi ChrtisB, I copied the xpath from the option giving @ rightclicking the html code. What do you advise to get the correct XPATH?

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking the href using the below code

`transacties = driver.find_element(By.ID, "ContentPlaceHolder1_lblTransactions") transacties.click()`

Comment: thank you for idea. I tried it and it raises error.

Comment: did you get the same error?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to click on a link.  See the example that I did w/ Amazon.  I find by CSS_SELECTOR.

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import Edge

```
dvr = Edge()
dvr.get("https://amazon.com")
dvr.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".a-link-normal.center-image.aok-block.image-window")[0].click()
```